# Overloading functions with virtual types of the same real type

Tags: c++, overloading

Header:

```
using PureCommand = QVector<qint8>;
using PureAnswer = QVector<qint8>;
using CommandName = QString;
using AnswerName = QString;
PureCommand nameToPure(CommandName commandName);
PureAnswer nameToPure(AnswerName answerName);
```

Cpp:

```
PureCommand Hasher::nameToPure(CommandName answerName) {
    return this->commandHash.find(commandName).value();
}

PureAnswer Hasher::nameToPure(AnswerName answerName) {
    return this->answerHash.find(answerName).value();
}
```

These give me build errors:

```
error: Hasher::nameToPure(AnswerName)' cannot be overloaded
error: with 'PureCommand Hasher::nameToPure(CommandName)'
```

These are just some simple functions but I have a lot of more complicated of a kind... I guess it's because e.g. PureCommand and PureAnswer are basically the same type but I've found this approach elegant and easy to work with. If it can't be done, I'll just lengthen the function names to make e.g. commandNameToPure(CommandName commandName) and answerNameToPure(AnswerName answerName) but I was just wondering what's really wrong here.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. IIRC, in order for overloading to work, the arguments can't refer to the same underlying type, otherwise you're effectively providing two conflicting definitions for the same function.

Comment: @Emmet, well, okay, thanks... too bad. :P

Comment: What you want is something like an opaque typedef. It currently doesn't exist in C++ (IIRC there've been some proposals..). Typical workarounds are composition or inheritance (= define a new class type).